# How to add class to links that variates

Tags: jquery

I use a free punBB script and the links to the users profiles are like this: `/u1`, `/u2`, `/u3` etc.

I'm tryng to create a tooltip when someone is crossing the cursor to a userlink, but first, I need to add a class to those links and i don't know how, because, it differ for every user.

For a single link I use:

```
$(function() {

    jQuery('a').each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == "/u1") {
            $(this).addClass('profile');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Why not just add the class server-side?

Comment: Could you just put a class of "userlink" on each of the a tags you want to highlight?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('a[href^="u/"]').addClass('profile')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try indexOf, and change /u1 to more specific like /usr1, /usr2

```
$(function() {

jQuery('a').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).attr("href").indexOf("/usr") != -1) {
        $(this).addClass('profile');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: I would assume that if the URL structure could be changed, it would be a simple matter to just include the CSS class without using Javascript

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, I assume you can't just add the class to the HTML output in the first place. If you can modify the script, I would suggest doing that otherwise, the general approach above would work, although I think this would be a better combination of performance and precision:

```
    $(function() {
        // Only fetch link elements with HREF beginning with "/u"
        $('a[href^="/u"]').each(function() {
            // For each of these elements, make sure its HREF actually matches the pattern
            // "/u" + <digits> before adding class
            if (/^\/u\d+$/.test($(this).attr('href'))) {
                $(this).addClass('profile');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: D'oh! Yours is definitely more efficient with the better anchor selector. Might be worth noting that the regular expression will only work for relative links as written, if it was absolute the ^ will cause the test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to pattern match the user links

```
// pattern match /u999
var uregex = /\/u\d+/;

$(function() {
    jQuery('a').each(function() {
        // get href value
        var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        // test to see if it matches the user profile pattern
        if(uregex.test(href)) {
            $(this).addClass('profile');
        }
    });
});
```